# How can I fix vertical alignment of Angular Material md-icon?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to fix alignment of md-icon as shown in the picture (please click "Angular card" below)

When I don't define height and width of button, icon overlaps the button. But problem is that, they together go down and don't follow vertical align (as navigate_next does now). In this case I have defined height and width of button, but now icon doesn't overlap the button as in the picture.

**HTML part**

```
<md-card class="product">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img md-card-image src="assets/cake.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="product-place">
        <md-card-footer>
          <md-icon>location_on</md-icon>
          <span>Resto Sudi Mampir Co</span>
          <button  md-icon-button>
            <md-icon>navigate_next</md-icon>
          </button>
        </md-card-footer>
      </div>
    </md-card>
```

**CSS part**

```
.product {
  width: 300px;
}
img {
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}
md-card-footer {
  background-color: #FEE436;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #4B493F;
}
button {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
md-icon {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
  span {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Angular card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RprQp.png)